# Need to understand the query in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'update loc_final_2 set county = ''' || TRIM(upper(county) ) || ''' 
    where city = '''
|| TRIM(upper(city) ) || ''' and state = ''' || TRIM(upper(state) ) || ''';'
FROM audtr_rgn_assgnmnts; 
commit
```

can somebody tell me what the above query does. There's a table called `loc_final_2` and another one called `audtr_rgn_assgnmnts`. I don't understand what the query is doing and I need to improve this query. But before that I have to understand what it is doing. I also need to know what commit is doing at the end.

Comment: this query  generates update statement, for distinct records in the table, but does not execute those updates statements

Comment: The values for county , city and state from audtr_rgn_assgnmnts is assigned and update statement is generated for all distinct values ...like this'       update loc_final_2 set county = 'US' where city = 'chicago' and state = 'illinois'; commit';

Comment: @kanagaraj what is 3 single quote doing over there? -   '''

Comment: This will make value to be passed to a variable or column in building sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is trying to generate multiple update statements  for the table loc_final_2 using the values from audtr_rgn_assgnmnts. 
I'm not sure why the `commit` exists there as the queries are not being executed.

If at all the intention of the original coder of the query was to run multiple updates, then I would say it's a wrong approach. A single update / MERGE like this would be more straightforward  and performant.

```
UPDATE loc_final_2 l
SET
     county = (
          SELECT upper(TRIM(county) ) --Add MIN/MAX if there are multiple rows 
          FROM audtr_rgn_assgnmnts a
          WHERE l.city = upper(TRIM(a.city) ) AND l.state = upper(TRIM(a.state) )
     );


MERGE INTO loc_final_2 t USING audtr_rgn_assgnmnts s ON (
     l.city = upper(TRIM(a.city) ) AND l.state = upper(TRIM(a.state) )
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.county = UPPER(TRIM(s.county));
```

If there are multiple rows, you would need to do a select distinct in the `USING`

```
MERGE INTO loc_final_2 t USING (
     SELECT DISTINCT city,
                     state,
                     upper(TRIM(s.county) ) AS county
     FROM audtr_rgn_assgnmnts
)
s ON (
     l.city = upper(TRIM(a.city) ) AND l.state = upper(TRIM(a.state) )
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.county = s.county;
```

**EDIT** :

> what is the 3-single quote doing in the query

A literal quote in Oracle needs to be escaped using another single quote.
So, If your final query  needs to have something like `a='b'` , the expression generating that string should be `a=||'''b||'''`  one the quite itself, one quote to escape that quote, other the part of concatenation.

> because min/max can be used only for numbers, right?

`MAX` and `MIN` can be used on strings. Here I said you may use it to avoid duplicate values for same county returned from the inner query. `DISTINCT` is also an option if you don't want to use `MIN/MAX`.

Comment: what is the 3-single quote doing in the query that I mentioned as in  -    '''  ? If you can answer that, it would be really good.

Comment: Also, max and min would be used in case of numbers, right? because min/max can be used only for numbers, right?

Comment: also, when you mentioned multiple rows, was that in the source or the target table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?
"
If at all the intention of the original coder of the query was to run multiple updates, then I would say it's a wrong approach". I want to know why yours is better than the other.

Comment: @bipin : It means there is no need to run multiple update statements for this requirement, a single update is more efficient.

Comment: Nayk In the first query box, there are two queries - one with update and the other with merge into. Are both of these queries part of the same task or are they just two different ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: @bipin : 2 different ways to update from another table.